# Selenium Web Driver - Uploading of file without visible text field for entering of absolute path

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I'm an automation QA engineer on Selenium Web Driver. How can I upload a file when there is no visible text field for entering of it's absolute path?

There is a Drag and Drop field and System pop up for file selection is shown after click on it.

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04, Selenium WebDriver 2.45.0

You can try it here http://www.megafileupload.com

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using 'Robot'.

Once you click on element which results into popup window, use following code which will upload a file -

```
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(pathOfFileToUpload);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);

Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);

robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

robot.delay(3000);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```